# Nested each statement using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use two arrays to populate a couple of each statements instead of writing it out 20 times for every attribute.

Here's what I was thinking. The idea here is to get the data (stored in `mainData`). I need a number of objects from this data, so I put those in an array (`$dataPoints`). I'm taking all of this data an appending it to a table. I'm adding the data to specific rows with specific `id`s (stored in `$tableIds`).

So, the basic idea...for every item in `$dataPoints`, look up that part of the data and append it to the table in the place indicated by the `id`s in the same position in the array. Like so...

```
var $dataPoints = ['name','description','subtitle'];
var $tableIds = ['mNames','mDescription','mSubtitle'];
$.each($dataPoints, function(index, val) {
    $.each(mainData.val[index].source_values, function(index, val) {
        $("#matrix_datatable").find('#'+$tableIds[index])
          .append($('<td class="tableCells">')
          .append(val.value + '</td>')
        )
    });
});
```

However, this line:

```
$.each(mainData.val[index].source_values, function(index, val) {
```

is throwing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

What am I missing here? Is there a simpler way to do this?

EDIT: Note that this works perfectly.

```
$.each(mainData.subtitle.source_values, function(index, val) {
    $("#matrix_datatable").find('#mSubtitle')
      .append($('<td class="tableCells">')
      .append(val.value + '</td>')
    )
});
```

However, I don't want to write this out for the 20 different objects within `mainData`.

Comment: Please post sample data

Comment: Is `mainData.val` an array of length > 1?

Comment: We cannot help you with code we cannot see. Clearly, if it's blowing up on that line, `mainData.val` has no `"0"` property.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable. You want `mainData[val]`, not `mainData.val`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. This got me past the errors, but the data populates the table in the wrong positions. Instead of going across rows for the same attribute, it's just going down columns and starting at the top of the next column once the rows are all filled.

Comment: @jonmrich: I suggest deleting this question, doing a bit more debugging (stepping through the code with your debugger, etc.), and if you still can't work it out, posting a new question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: @jonmrich: You not using the right `index` in the second each. That is the index of the first `each()` loop... Not the index of `mainData`. I would try `$.each(mainData[val].source_values` at first... Maybe you don't even need to provide an `index`... Can't be sure without seeing the json structure (Which you should post a sample).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably meant:

```
mainData[val][index].source_values
```

Writing `mainData.val` literally looks for a key `val` in `mainData`.